# stm32l431 Read multiple channels ADC

Tags: stm32, adc, embedded, stm32cubemx, stm32cubeide

I am trying to read from 2 channels of ADC 1, I have followed other tutorials and tried but I am not getting any success. I can read from one channel but not the other.

ADC configuration:
[image]

[image]

This is my polling code that runs in a while loop.

```
 HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1);

         HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc1, 100);
         i_ADC_1_reading = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);


         HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc1, 100);
         i_ADC_2_reading = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);



         HAL_ADC_Stop(&hadc1);
```

Why is Channel 1 and 2 containing the same reading?, I had a look at the reference manual and I could not see anything specific.

Comment: Maybe the two pins are shorted together or, the same voltage is on both pins.

Comment: Not the case unfortunately, I did a continuity test.

Comment: What is under the Rank settings?  Isn't that where you need to select the channel and the sampling time?

Comment: Yes, currently rank 1 is channel 5 with a sampling time of 2.5 cycles. Ranks 2 is Channel 6 with a sampling time of 2.5 cycles

Comment: Is the reading correct for either channel?  Try a much longer sampling time.  The sampling time allows the ADC input signal to settle after changing the channel.